# ASP.NET self delete user

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql

I am making a website using ASP.NET and SQL, and I need to add an option for every user to delete his account. From the admin panel I have no problems deleting users but I want users to be able to delete themselves, but something is not working. Here is my HTML (the important part of it, at least):

```
 ...
 <%=editUser %>
 ...
```

Here is the cs:

```
public string editUser = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // page protection
    if (Session["user"] == null || Session["user"]=="")
    {
        Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx");
    }

    string fileName = "MsSqlDB.mdf";
    string idNum = Session["idNum"].ToString();

    // Deleting the user
    if (Request.Form["delete"] != null) // if button is clicked
    {
        string sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM support WHERE idNum = '" + idNum + "'";
        MyAdoHelper.DoQuery(fileName, sqlQuery);
        Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
    }
    ...
    editUser += "<input type='button' name='delete' id = 'delete' value='Delete User' class = 'btn btn-danger'/>";
}
```

**What happens?** When I click the delete button nothing happens.

Comment: I'm not clear about where you came up with `if (Request.Form["delete"] != null) // if button is clicked`.  How is that supposed to work?

Comment: did you debug to check weather your "if" condition is working?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan: It probably isn't.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's how I learned in school to check whether a button was clicked with ASP.NET. Do you have a better way to do so? Thanks for the quick comment!

Comment: Is this supposed to be "normal" ASP.NET (not any special framework or anything? If so, the delete button should have a event handler, not be checking in form load like that. And the button needs a runat=server. this looks more like classic ASP than .NET...